# Pass a function with the arguments in C++

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Is it possible in C++ to pass a function WITH it's parameters as an argument? I don't want to just pass the function name. I want to pass the function name with the parameters included.  Note that I don't know how many parameters the function recieves nor the types. That is why I am not adding them as extra parameters. I just want a reference to a function call that I can execute on demand. For example:

```
CallFunction(f(param1, param2));
```

But f is not evaluated, I just get a reference to the function call and I can evaluate it when I want, for example:

```
CallFunction(f){
 //do something and then in one moment do:
 f; // and this calls f(param1, param2)
}
```

Any way in which this can be achieved in C++? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @songyuanyao is it possible to then get the information of the call as a string, e.g. The bañe of the function that is being called?

Comment: Sorry, what is `bañe`?

Comment: Perhaps `CallFunction` could accept a templated callable and invokes it without arguments. The caller then simply pass it a lambda that accepts no arguments and, when called, invokes `f(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

A complete example of using `std::bind`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f(int p1, int p2) {
    std::cout << "In f(" << p1 << "," << p2 << ")\n";
}

template <typename F>
void CallFunction(F f)
{
    std::cout << "Start CallFunction\n";
    f();
    std::cout << "End CallFunction\n";
}

int main()
{
    CallFunction(std::bind(f, 2, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Accept any callable function as the first argument
2. Use variadic templates and accept any number of arguments of any type.
3. Use perfect forwarding.

http://ideone.com/z2kLUx

```
int HelloWorld(string var1, const char* var2)
{
    cout << var1 << " " << var2 << endl;
    return 5;
}

template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
auto CallFunction(Fn fn, Args&&... args)
{
     return fn(forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Value returned: " << CallFunction(HelloWorld,"Hello","World");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the simple version, which has a drawback: you have to specify a function that returns non-void, but this can be fixed easily. The easy fix is create another CallFunction that returns void with a different name, or use `std::enable_if`.

http://ideone.com/El3WUi

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
auto CallFunction(Fn fn, Args&&... args) -> typename enable_if<is_same<void, decay_t<decltype(fn(forward<Args>(args)...))>>::value, decltype(fn(forward<Args>(args)...))>::type
{
    fn(forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
auto CallFunction(Fn fn, Args&&... args) -> typename enable_if<!is_same<void, decay_t<decltype(fn(forward<Args>(args)...))>>::value, decltype(fn(forward<Args>(args)...))>::type
{
    return fn(forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

One is to create a wrapper closure that will encapsulate the call to your function. This has the advantage that you can transform the output of your function if necessary.

Doing a simple wrapper is identical to using the `std::bind` as others have mentioned before.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void CallFunction(std::function<void(void)> f) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    auto closure = [](int a, int b) {
        std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
    };

    auto wrapper = [closure]() {
        closure(1, 2);
    };

    CallFunction(wrapper);

    CallFunction(std::bind(closure, 3, 4));

    return 0;
}
```